# Equality of algebra maps defined on the tensor algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space. We defined the tensor algebra $T(V):=\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}T^n$, where $T^0=k, T^1=V, T^n=V^{\otimes n}$.

Besides we have the inclusion $i:V\to T(V), v\mapsto v\in T^1$.

If we have two algebra maps $T(V)\to A$ into some $k$-algebra $A$, what is needed to be done in order to show that they are equal?

I guess that the set $\{i(v):v\in V\}$ generates $T(V)$ as an algebra, so it would be enough to check this equality on those elements. Is that true?

But how does this set generates $T^0=k$?

Comment: $k$ is obtained by applying constant polynomials to this set.

Comment: So it is indeed enough to chec equaloty on those elements $i(v)$?

Comment: Yes. A $k$-algebra homomorphism necessarily sends any element of $k$ to itself, so there is no way your two homomorphisms can differ on these elements.

Comment: Can you explain why? What you really mean is that $\lambda.1$ is send to itself, don`t you?

Comment: I mean that a $k$-algebra homomorphism $A \to B$ must send $\lambda \cdot 1_A$ to $\lambda \cdot 1_B$ (because it is $k$-linear and sends $1_A$ to $1_B$).